# rails: prevent flash message from showing twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the correct way to set a flash message for the current view but not show it for the next request. In other words usually you set the flash message and redirect and the flash message gets shown on the redirect. I don't want to redirect and so I need to make sure the flash message doesn't get shown twice.

Comment: make sure that you put your flash massage in any action you want to display, not in application layout

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/4614017/246263 for more information

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
flash.now[:notice] = 'message'
```

Answer (score 24):

if you are to 'render' the page, use `flash.now[:notice]`, when you want to 'redirect', use `flash[:notice]`

Comment: This is the correct way to use .now and should be voted as the correct answer.