# Why does validation error appear on the form after successful submit and going back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, form-submit, back-button, validationerror

I'm using Rails 4 and Chrome. The following results in the situation:

1. Post a form that causes a validation error (ie. "Name cannot be empty")
2. Post that same form successfully by correcting the input
3. Hit the browser back button and the validation error from step 1 is shown on the input field even though it has a value that is not empty

Why does the validation error from the step 1 pop back and how to fix this behaviour? Note: Turbolinks is in use, could that be the reason?

Here's the way to replicate:

```
rails g scaffold Page name:string

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

> ```
> Navigate to /pages/new
> Submit (errors appear on the form)
> Fillout the name
> Submit again (redirected to successfully created model)
> Hit the browser back button (the validation errors are there, and the field is filled with the last supplied value)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using something like the following code to send back the errors related to the record being created/updated:

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
    # your logic when successfull
  else
    render :edit, flash[:errors] = @post.errors
  end
end
```

Or something similar. My point here is that you should use the following syntax for setting the errors in the `flash` :

```
flash.now[:errors] = @post.errors
```

**(1)** This should set the `flash[:errors]` **available only for the current page** and delete it right after you leave this page.

**(2)** You could also use `flash.clear` at the end of your view, but this is not how it is supposed to be done, and seems a little bit "hacky".

---

Resources:

- **(1)** [Rails' documentation about `flash`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)
- **(2)** [`flash.clear` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-clear)
- **(1)** & **(2)** [Why flash message won't disappear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613952/why-flash-message-wont-disappear)

Comment: Hey buddy! I'm not using flash messages, just standard Rails form and model validations.

Comment: Added an example to clarify the situation! Thanks!